# Currency switch not showing in modules homepage

Tags: magento-1.9

When i activate the EUR to PND switch for currency it wont show on the modules of the theme. I think it doesn't have the conversion rate checker or pricing PHP lines to do that. What do I need to add for this in for example this file:

```
<?php
   $sym = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(); 
   $price = $_product->getPrice();
   $specialprice = $_product->getFinalPrice(); // $specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
   if($price != $specialprice){
      if($price != ''){
     echo '<p class="old-price"><span class="price-label">';
     echo $this->__('Regular Price'). ': </span>';
     echo '<span id="old-price-'.$_product->getId().'" class="price">'.$sym.''.number_format($price,2).'</span></p>';
    }
    if($specialprice != '')
    {
     echo '<p class="special-price">
      <span class="price-label">Special Price</span>
      <span id="product-price-384'.$_product->getId().'" class="price">'.$sym.''.number_format($specialprice,2).'</span>
     </p> ';
    } 
   }else {
    echo '<div class="price-box">
     <span id="product-price-'.$_product->getId().'" class="regular-price">
      <span class="price">'.$sym.''.number_format($price,2).'</span>                                    
     </span>    
    </div>';    
   }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below currency converter code.

```
$price = $_product->getPrice();
$baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode(); 
$currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();

// convert price from current currency to base currency
$priceOne = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($price, $currentCurrencyCode, $baseCurrencyCode); 


// convert price from base currency to current currency
$priceTwo = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($price, $baseCurrencyCode, $currentCurrencyCode);
```

Instead of using all the symbol and number format thing, just use default Magento price display function.

```
echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($priceTwo, true, false);
```

It will display the price with current currency symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should go to “System->Manage Currency Rates” and set rates for currencies you’ve chosen before. You can use Webservicex to import currency rates from Webservicex service. Here’s how it looks like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is not what is going wrong. I've got it working, but not for the prices of the modules of the site like featuredproductslider.phtml etc.

Comment: Get currency symbol by currency code : `$currency_symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();`

Comment: Get Current currency code :
`$currentCurrency = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();`